# Enable/Disable Submit Button using jQuery (and bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, bootstrap-4, electron

I have a few fields that unfortunately didn't fit within the `<form>` tag. I want to have the form disabled on load, until a user inputs on multiple fields at least, and then the button will enable.

Now I have 2 problems. One of which is, for the jquery code that works, it can only work on one field on function. What if I want multiple fields as a function.....is there a way to do that? Another problem is for those familiar with Bootstrap 4, there seems to be a problem with the 'disabled' function. Even when I put in `disabled` inside a `button` or `a` class, it is still clickable. Even I tried to add `tabindex="-1"` as it suggests in the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/buttons/#disabled-state), but to no avail.

Here's the HTML (didn't want the bootstrap in there because of clutter):

```
<p>User ID</p>
<input class="form-control" id="UserIDField" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" style="width: 146px;" type="text" required>
<p>Message</p>
<textarea class="form-control" id="MessageField" rows="5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" title="Message is required!" required></textarea>
<p>Select date</p>
<input id="DatePicker" type="text" placeholder="Click to select" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" aria-label="Date" data-zdp_readonly_element="false" style="position: relative; float: none; top: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: auto; margin: 0px; padding-right: 40px;" required>
<button type="button" id="ScheduleButton" tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block disabled" data-toggle="tooltip" aria-disabled="true" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" title="Your message is sent!"><i class="fas fa-inbox"></i> Schedule to Send Message</button>
```

(note the button id `ScheduleButton` is the button to submit the form)

And here's the javascript/jquery inside a render.js file.

```
 $('#MessageField').on('input change', function () {
            if ($(this).val() != '') {
                $('#ScheduleButton').removeClass('disabled');
                $('#ModalButton').removeClass('disabled');
                $('#ScheduleButton').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#ModalButton').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else {
                $('#ScheduleButton').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#ModalButton').prop('disabled', true);
            }
});
```

I can't use a `document.SOMETHING` as it's in Electron (unless I add that in a HTML file.

Comment: You can handle the form change with `$("form :input").change(function() { .. });` The callback will be called for every change of any input.

Comment: That could help, but would that be for _all_ input fields in a `<form>` tag? What if there's another field associated with a different submit button, would pretty much anything that has a input field would go out of whack?

Comment: 1) The easiest would be to test it yourself ;) but it should work for *all* input fields in the form tag, obviously you need to change the selector to only match your form since `$("form :input")` matches all the forms on the page. 2) In the callback function you can choose what to do for each of the input fields. So if it's a field associated with another submit button just do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` and `change` events will *bubble*. Meaning that a parent element surrounding both inputs can capture these events. I don't know what you mean with *a few fields that unfortunately didn't fit within the  tag*, for this example I still used one.

The example below here will listen for the `input` event on the form element. Whenever one of the inputs have their values changed it will check if all fields have valid (in this case; not empty) values.

When either field has an input that is empty it will set the `areFieldsValid` boolean to `false`, meaning the field is not valid. This value is then used to either set or remove the `disabled` attribute from the button in the form.

**Edit**

With the right selector, you can specify which inputs to check on which to leave out.

```js
const $form = $('.form');
const $inputs = $form.find('input.validate');
const $button = $form.find('button');

$form.on('input', '.validate', function(event) {
  let areFieldsValid = true;
    
  $.each($inputs, function() {
    const $input = $(this);
    if ($input.val() === '') {
      areFieldsValid = false;
    }
  });
  
  $button.prop('disabled', !areFieldsValid);
});
```

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <label for="first-name">First name (validate)</label>
  <input id="first-name" class="validate" type="text" name="first_name">
  <label for="last-name">Last name</label>
  <input id="last-name" type="text" name="last_name">
  <label for="address">Address</label>
  <input id="address" type="text" name="address">
  <label for="country">Country (validate)</label>
  <input id="country" class="validate" type="text" name="country">
  <button type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

### Edit

This snippet below works with the id selectors like you want.

```js
const $form = $('.your-form');
const $inputs = $form.find('#UserIDField, #MessageField, #DatePicker');
const $buttons = $form.find('#ScheduleButton, #ModalButton');

$form.on('input', function() {
  let areFieldsValid = true;

  $.each($inputs, function() {
    const $input = $(this);
    if ($input.val() === '') {
      areFieldsValid = false;
    }
  });

  $buttons.prop('disabled', !areFieldsValid);
});
```

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="your-form">
  <input class="form-control validate" id="UserIDField" data-formPage="Main" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="text" placeholder="User ID Field" required>

  <textarea class="form-control validate" placeholder="Message Field" id="MessageField" data-formPage="Main" rows="5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" title="Message is required!" required></textarea>


  <input id="DatePicker" type="text" placeholder="Date Picker Field" data-formPage="Main" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" aria-label="Date" data-zdp_readonly_element="false" style="position: relative; float: none; top: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: auto; margin: 0px; padding-right: 40px;"
    required>

  <button type="button" id="ScheduleButton" tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block disabled" data-toggle="tooltip" aria-disabled="true" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" title="Your message is sent to be scheduled!" disabled>That Button should enable when fields are filled</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That could help, but would that be for _all_ input fields in a `<form>` tag? What if there's another field in the same page, but in a modal associated with a different submit button, would pretty much anything that has a input field would go out of whack? For instance, as just like that shown, but there's another field associated with a different button but not in a `<form>` tag.

Comment: Yes, however you are able to select specific elements in the form. I've modified the example to show how you can validation more specific. Now it will only need the First name and Country fields to be filled in.

Comment: Ok, i saw the edit, I know of the CSS selectors, could I just use just these inputs to associate the button using the `id` CSS selector? Ie. `$('#NameOrIDofElement').doSomething`

Comment: Sure, it would do the same but just be more specific. The same would be `const $button = $form.find('#NameOrIDofElement');` if the button has that specific ID. I'd recommend storing the results of the selectors in variables. That way you only have to look for the element once and use the result of the search in the rest of your code.

Comment: And I can do the same to inputs? Just have variables for finding a input ID in a form? For instance `const $THIS_IS_a_INPUT = $form.find('#messageField');`

Comment: You can, but it won't work like you describe. This is how you would select multiple inputs by id: `const $inputs = $form.find('#SomeInput, #SomeOtherInput, #AnotherInput');`. Or if you want a single input: `const $someInput = $form.find('#SomeInput');`

Comment: ok, I did just that, but now with the inputs, the buttons kept disabled. I put the attribute `required` on the input fields, and even added the attribute `disabled` on the button. here's the code `const $form = $('[data-formPage="Main"]');
const $inputs = $form.find('#UserIDField, #MessageField, #DatePicker');
const $button = $form.find('#ScheduleButton, #ModalButton');`

Comment: That should mean that one of your selectors might be incorrect. Could you create a runnable example to examine?

Comment: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mikey186/xbaqvhck) on JSfiddle. I had to put the [attribute=value] as it would get the container.

Comment: Did you forget to add a form / parent around your inputs? It won't work without it.

Comment: Just use a class or id to select your form element.
And the `form.on('input', '.validate', function(event) {});` function is not only triggered by elements that have a `validate` class on them. Remove the string from the function.

Comment: I tried putting everything in the `<form>` to no avail. Also for the `DatePicker` ID, I couldn't add the `validate` to the ID due to the input being tied to a npm module using that input.

Comment: Have you seen that I've updated the answer and included the code from your fiddle?

Comment: Ahh I didn't see the extra edit. and apparently I'm a idiot, I forgot to get rid of the `.disabled` class when `disabled` is _already_ there in the attribute. It works now!

Comment: but what if there is multiple forms with a submit button? use the `function NameOFBlock() { ...... }`?

Comment: Then don't use ID's to select all those elements. Every ID on the page should be unique, so you should use classes instead. The first example I provided does just that. But, you'll need to select all the forms that you need and loop over them. For each form look for the inputs and buttons, and add an event listener.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, I believe your code works, all you need to do is add the disabled attribute inside of the button div so the page loads with the button disabled. Then when the user types the val changes and the disabled attribute is removed

```
<button type="button" id="ScheduleButton" tabindex="-1" 
class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block disabled" 
data-toggle="tooltip" aria-disabled="true" data-placement="top" 
data-trigger="manual" title="Your message is sent!" 
disabled>
      <i class="fas fa-inbox"></i> Schedule to Send Message
</button>
```

Here's a working example
https://jsfiddle.net/70m6kqud/

Comment: it almost works, but it only works on the first 2 fields, with the `DatePicker` input left out of the condition.